# Can not connect home network devices from internet // Cablecom deferring my requests

Tags: networking, nat, internet, blocking

I reciently moved to Switzerland. I was trying to set my home network configuration as I'm used to (SSH Access to my box, VPN Server, ...) I did the configuration on the router and I was even able to connect using my public IP from my home network. But outside my home network (say at the university), when I try to connect to my home network, another server blocks my requests. `178-82-220-54.dynamic.hispeed.ch` answers instead (when connecting to `178.82.220.54`). Is there anyway I can overcome that blocking?

Best Regards!

Comment: You mention that "another server blocks my request" - how do you see this?

Comment: Because when I use ping, I get answer from `178-82-220-54.dynamic.hispeed.ch` and traceroute 'dies' (ends up) there

Comment: If your only data to support your claim that another server blocks your requests is that a traceroute does not reach your destination, I would suggest that it's more likely that your router is not replying to ICMP externally (and as such your final hop shown in traceroute is the final router responding to ICMP on the path between testing client and your host)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your ISP is blocking SSH access using a rudimentary firewall configuration or similar on one of the interim routers; I'd suggest selecting a random high port number (say, 59876), and having your SSH daemon listen on that port, then configuring your router to forward this port to your SSH server host. You may still find that your ISP blocks these such ports as well; it may also be an idea to simply contact them and enquire as to if this is the case, why it is the case if so, and whether you can have the restriction lifted for your connection.

Comment: what if I use the 'exposed host' configuration to my pc, then I run portscan?

Comment: That may give you a reasonable idea of what is and is not available externally, yes.

Comment: Is it legally safe? I mean, if request are going to cablecom server, will they take the port scan as a some sort of attack or would be offended?

Comment: Personally I would take the stance that probing the tcp/udp ports of your own external IP address is fairly defensible but of course I cannot speak to the terms and conditions of your service provider. I would be surprised if they even noticed however, no less took any issue with it. (automated bots scan vast swathes of the internet literally all the time and very little is done by ISPs about them)